# How can I specify which instance to create Metric on?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cdk

Just getting started with CDK, implementing simple monitoring to raise an alarm when an RDS instance is low on Storage space.

```
    //Alarm creation for low RDS free storage        
    const dbStorageAlarm = new cloudwatch.Alarm(this, "DB Low Storage Space", {
      metric: dbStorage, // want to use out of the box free storage space rds metric
      threshold: 1073741824, //1 GB
      evaluationPeriods: 3,
      datapointsToAlarm: 2,
    });
```

FreeStorageSpace is an out of the box cloudwatch metric, available for each RDS instance. How can I expose the out of the box metric and use it to create alarms via CDK? Additionally, how can I specify which RDS instance to attach the metric to since I have multiple?  The only documentation I can find on using existing metrics is here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/how_to_set_cw_alarm.html.

Answer (score 1):

For many L2 constructs there are already build-in out of the box metric creation methods. As far as I see in the [RDS DatabaseInstance CDK docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_rds.DatabaseInstance.html#metricwbrfreewbrstoragewbrspaceprops) You can do this as well for Your RDS instance.
Consider following code:

```js
const instance: DatabaseInstance = createDbInstance()
    //the props are exemplary! Check out what You need
    instance
      .metricFreeStorageSpace({
        statistic: 'Average',
        unit: Unit.KILOBYTES,
        period: Duration.seconds(60),
      })
      .createAlarm(this, 'myFreeStorageSpaceRDSAlarm', {
        alarmName: 'MyRDSAlarm',
        evaluationPeriods: 3,
        datapointsToAlarm: 2,
        threshold: 1073741824,
      })
```

This way You can create the metric for the particular instance object and also create an Alert if You want to.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Don't have enough rep to up vote unfortunately, will be sure to do so once I do!